# Regex to split string by space and number using preg_split in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, regex, preg-split

I need to split a string by number and by spaces but not sure the regex for that. My code is:

```
$array = preg_split('/[0-9].\s/', $content);
```

The value of $content is:

```
Weight 229.6104534866 g
Energy 374.79170898476 kcal
Total lipid (fat) 22.163422468932 g
Carbohydrate, by difference 13.641848209743 g
Sugars, total 4.3691034101428 g
Protein 29.256342349938 g
Sodium, Na 468.99386390008 mg
```

Which gives the result:

```
Array ( [0] => Weight 229.61045348 [1] => g
Energy 374.791708984 [2] => kcal
Total lipid (fat) 22.1634224689 [3] => g
Carbohydrate, by difference 13.6418482097 [4] => g
Sugars, total 4.36910341014 [5] => g
Protein 29.2563423499 [6] => g
Sodium, Na 468.993863900 [7] => mg
) 1
```

I need to split the text from the number but not sure how, so that:

```
[0] => Weight
[1] => 229.60145348
[2] => g
```

and so on...

I also need it to ignore the commas, brackets and spaces where the label is. When using explode I found that 'Total lipid (fat)' instead of being one value separated into 3 values, not sure how to fix that with regex.

When using explode() I get:

```
[0] => Total
[1] => lipid
[2] => (fat)
```

but I need those values as one for a label, any way to ignore that?

Any help is very appreciated!

Comment: Why don't use the `explode()` function ?

Comment: Please can you [edit] to include a [mre] - show us the input that the output you've printed comes from, and the exact output you want for that input.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of splitting, you might very well *match and capture* the required parts, e.g. with the following pattern:

```
^(?P<category>\D+)\s+(?P<value>[\d.]+)\s+(?P<unit>.+)
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/zKky1I/1).

---

In `PHP` this could be

```
<?php

$data = 'Weight 229.6104534866 g
Energy 374.79170898476 kcal
Total lipid (fat) 22.163422468932 g
Carbohydrate, by difference 13.641848209743 g
Sugars, total 4.3691034101428 g
Protein 29.256342349938 g
Sodium, Na 468.99386390008 mg ';

$pattern = '~^(?P<category>\D+)\s+(?P<value>[\d.]+)\s+(?P<unit>.+)~m';

preg_match_all($pattern, $data, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

// Print the entire match result
print_r($matches);
?>
```

See [**a demo on ideone.com**](https://ideone.com/k3uzWD).

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to using a `preg_` functions, `sscanf()` allows the decimal value to be explicitly typed as a float (if that is valuable).

Unfortunately due to the greedy nature of `sscanf()`, the space between the label and the float value will still be attached to the label string.  If this is a problem, the label value will need to be `rtrim()`ed.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/8lIhS))

```
// $contentLines = file('path/to/content.txt');
$contentLines = [
    'Weight 229.6104534866 g',
    'Energy 374.79170898476 kcal',
    'Total lipid (fat) 22.163422468932 g',
    'Carbohydrate, by difference 13.641848209743 g',
    'Sugars, total 4.3691034101428 g',
    'Protein 29.256342349938 g',
    'Sodium, Na 468.99386390008 mg',
];

var_export(
    array_map(
        fn($line) => sscanf(
            $line,
            '%[^0-9]%f%s',
        ),
        $contentLines
    )
);
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to everyone for the help. I found that by adding a double space in between all values then setting the explode parameter to the double space it ignored what I needed.

Comment: Look into the answers, this is surely not the best solution, actually.